# How to format an input file in bash to a special format?

Tags: bash

i have a textfile i generate via a bash script from various server crontabs that looks like this format:

```
0 sys1 server1
5 sys2 server2
2,3 sys3
0 sys3 server3
7 sys4 server4
....
```

And i want it to get formated to this:

```
0 sys1 server1
5 sys2 server2
2 sys3 server3
3 sys3 server3
0 sys3 server3
7 sys4 server4
....
```

The problem i have is that i it can always change if there are two numbers per sys/server or more and there could be also more than two crontab entries for each server.

My attempt was something like this:

```
    rday_old=""
    rsys_old=""
    rser_old=""
    [[ -e output ]] && rm output
    while read -u5 -r -a line; do
            rday=${line[0]}
            rsys=${line[1]}
            rser=${line[2]} 
            if [[ "$rsys_old" == "$rsys" ]]; then
                    echo "$rday_old $rsys_old $rser" >> output
            else
                    echo "$rday $rsys $rser" >> output    
            fi   
            rday_old=$rday
            rsys_old=$rsys
            rser_old=$rser  
    done 5< input_file
```

The problem ist obviously that it won't work like intended. I don't know what the best way to solve this is. My attemp doesn't take into account that the day needs to be split if it is in the format of 2,3 oder even 2,4,5 up to 7 days in crontab format (which would be an * sign). Additionally it could happen that i need to store more than one rday_old, rsys_old and rser_old.

I hope i stated my problem in a way that is understandable.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Edit:

After the answer of @anishsane i fixed his answer to

```
cat input | awk '{sys=$2; ser=$3; split($1,a,","); for(i in a){print a[i]" "  sys " " ser}}' > output
```

but it outputs now as result:

```
0 sys1 server1
5 sys2 server2
2 sys3 
3 sys3 server3
0 sys3 server3
7 sys4 server4
....
```

So i am almost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`gawk`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions) approach:

```
$ cat srvlist
0 sys1 server1
5 sys2 server2
2,3 sys3
0 sys3 server3
7 sys4 server4

$ awk '{sys=gensub("sys","","",$2); split($1,a,","); for(i in a){print a[i] " sys" sys " server" sys}}' srvlist
0 sys1 server1
5 sys2 server2
2 sys3 server3
3 sys3 server3
0 sys3 server3
7 sys4 server4
```

explanation:

1. `sys` variable extracts the number out of second field - sys1, sys3 etc. (This would contain 1, 3 respectively)
2. split first field by comma as delimiter into array `a`
3. print the string as desired with loop over `a`
4. Field 3 in the input file is ignored. At least for the input provided, field2 & 3 always have the same number.

Comment: Updated the original question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import fileinput
import re

for line in fileinput.input():
    matches = re.match('(\d),(\d) sys(\d+)', line)
    if matches:
        first, last, sys = matches.groups()
        for ii in range(int(first), int(last) + 1):
            print ii, 'sys' + sys, 'server' + sys
    else:
        print line,
```

It uses a simple regex to match lines with a comma in the first field.  If it matches, lines are printed from the beginning to the end of the numeric range.  Otherwise the original line is printed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
But i prefer a bash solution if possible. Otherwise it gets way to complicated with the amount of scripts i need to use. This problem above is just a small part of a way bigger job

Answer (score 0):

got it solved now:

```
[[ -e output ]] && rm output
tac input > rev_input
rser_old=""
while read -u5 -r -a line; do
        rday=${line[0]}
        rsys=${line[1]}
        rser=${line[2]}
        OIFS=$IFS
        IFS=','
        for x in $rday
        do
                [[ "$rser" == "" ]] && echo "$x $rsys $rser_old" >> output
                [[ "$rser" != "" ]] && echo "$x $rsys $rser" >> output
        done
        rser_old=$rser
        IFS=$OIFS
done 5< rev_input
```

output is obviously now reversed, but this doesn't matter at all since this part is just a step and output will be processed to antoher script now.

Thanks for the help provided.