# Process file with Bash script

Tags: bash

This is my first post, so kindly excuse me on the formatting..i did try

I have a txt file which are tab separated which looks like this

```
9574575052  2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1   V87.41      
9574582051  2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1   042|038.9|995.91        
9574583059  2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1   275.42|011.90
```

and I want to get an output tab separated like this

```
9574575052   2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1  V87.41      
9574582051  2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1   042     
9574582051  2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1   038.9  
9574582051  2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1   995.91  
9574583059  2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1   275.42  
9574583059  2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1   011.90
```

with my script I am getting the output as

```
9574575052 2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1 V87.41    
9574575052 2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1 V87.41    
9574575052 2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1 V87.41    
9574582051 2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1 042    
9574582051 2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1 038.9    
9574582051 2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1 995.91    
9574583059 2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1 275.42    
9574583059 2.16.840.1.113883.6.5.2.1 011.90
```

The first line is repeating twice, I am not sure where i am going wrong..After debugging a bit I understood that when bash is processing the first line,  f2 and f3 have the same text and f1...How can i correct this. Or is my approach itself wrong?

Below is my script

```
while read line; do   
file=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1,2)   
wrd=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f3)   
cd1=$(echo $wrd | cut -d'|' -f1)    
cd2=$(echo $wrd | cut -d'|' -f2)   
cd3=$(echo $wrd | cut -d'|' -f3)       
        if [ "$cd3" != "" ]; then    
                echo $file $cd1       
                echo $file $cd2       
                echo $file $cd3       

        else
            echo $file $cd1
            echo $file $cd2
        fi

done < "$1"
```

Comment: Please check the answer for this question: possible duplicate of [How to format an input file in bash to a special format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814005/how-to-format-an-input-file-in-bash-to-a-special-format)

Comment: Instead of using `cut` with `$line`, you can use, `while read file1 file2 wrd; do`

Comment: Did you try my answer? Do you require any additional clarification?

Comment: @TomFenech     Thank you..i did try ur answer and it worked, Only half way there..still duplicates are coming up ..but removed them by running unique command on the output file. However trying to get the whole part thru script itself.

Comment: The code I provided in my answer works for the input in the question, doesn't it? If you can change the example to include some lines it doesn't work for, perhaps I can modify my script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to do this:

```
awk -F'[|\t]' -vOFS="\t" '{for(i=3;i<=NF;++i)print $1,$2,$i}' file
```

This sets the input field separator to a tab or a pipe and the output separator to a tab. It loops through the last fields (from 3 to the end) printing each one along with the first and second fields.

For the record, writing your own `while read` loops and using `cut` is rarely necessary in the shell. The right tool for the job is awk!